# IntentService not getting called sometimes

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using an `IntentService` to access different web service methods and update my `ContentProvider`. The issue I'm seeing is that, *sometimes*, I send a new Intent to the IntentService but `onHandleIntent()` of the `IntentService` is not called. And after a while, playing with the application and clicking stuff to trigger other Intents, the `onHandleIntent()` method is called and all the queued `Intents` are run.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? It seems that the `IntentService` gets stuck at some point. I know it is asynchronous but I still expect it to run in a timely fashion. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you ever come up with a reproducible test case, post a project demonstrating it to http://b.android.com along with a description of the problem. What you are describing should not happen AFAIK. The only thing that should interrupt an `IntentService` would be the phone falling asleep.

Comment: OK. I'll try to create a test case when I have some time. In the meantime, I've switched to AsyncTasks where it is really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that a http request would take a long time and consequently, the other http requests would have to wait. IntentService uses only one thread at a time.