# IntentService not firing

Tags: android, service, intentservice

My application synchronizes data with a remote database via web service calls.  I make these calls in an IntentService so they can run in the background (I call it SyncService).

The code to launch my IntentService looks like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(appContext, SyncService.class);

// place additional values in intent
intent.putExtra("data_type", SyncService.ITEM_TRACKING);
intent.putExtra("user_id", intUserId);

// call SyncService
appContext.startService(intent);
```

This, normally, looks great.  However, one of my friends, who is also a user of my app, often tells me his data doesn't sync and get displayed on our website.  His device happened to be displaying the symptoms while I was around.  I plugged his device into my computer and here is what I found:

- The code to launch SyncService (ie: the code above) was hit.
- I had a breakpoint inside the onHandleIntent method of my IntentService and it **never** gets hit.
- I checked his device's list of running services and SyncService was there and running.  Interestingly, it had been running for about 20 minutes.  I was under the impression that IntentService killed itself when it was all out of Intents to process.
- I force stopped the SyncService (not the app) and, all of the sudden, onHandleIntent started getting hit over and over.  It was like all the Intents were queued up somewhere on the device and were just now getting thrown at the SyncService.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be the problem?  Do you think it's an issue with my app?  With Android?

Again, I am handing a message to Android saying, "Start this IntentService or send the message to the already running IntentService."  At that point, I have no control.  The message never gets to the IntentService.  Once I force quit the app, the messages get sent to the IntentService and it does its job.

UPDATE:  I think this code is fine, but I'll put it up since a lot of you may want to see it.

Every Intent that comes in to the IntentService has an Extra denoting what "type" of call is to me made (ie: do I call *this* web service or *that* web service, etc).  When an Intent comes in to the IntentService, I check the "type" and, if there is already an Intent in the queue for that type, I add an Extra to it called "skip" so, when it is reached, I don't execute the search (basically the IntentService can build up lots of Intents and it makes no sense to call *this* web service when *this* webservice was called 20 seconds ago).  It basically protects the app from spamming the website.

**It is important to note that none of this code is hit anyway (once the problem starts occurring).  onStartCommand does not get called until the app is killed**

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // here be dragons
        // overriding this method and adding your own code is dangerous. i've wrapped
        // my code in a try/catch because it is essential that the super method be called
        // every time this method is entered. any errors in my code should not prevent this
        // or the app will explode.
        try {
            if (flags == 0 && intent != null && intent.hasExtra("data_type")) {
                Integer intDataType = intent.getExtras().getInt("data_type");

                    if (!mCurrentTypes.containsKey(intDataType)
                            || !mCurrentTypes.get(intDataType)) {
                        mCurrentTypes.put(intDataType, true);  // put this type in the list and move on
                    }
                    else {
                        intent.putExtra("skip", true);  // mark this Intent to be skipped
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.e("Error onStartCommand", "error: " + e);
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


private void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        // do stuff if no "skip" Extra
        mCurrentTypes.put(intDataType, false);
    }
```

Comment: Did you register your service in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes.  Again, the service usually works.  My friend is the only person who has mentioned this problem.  And most of the time it works fine for him, but occasionally it gets... congested?

Comment: It looks like there is a code in your IntentService that causes the application to stick around for a long time. Since IntentServices are queued one after each other to be run sequentially, that explains why you get onHandleIntent getting hit over and over after killing the current IntentService. If you can post your IntentService code, we might be able to identify why it is getting stuck there.

Comment: Hmm... my IntentService code is very large (I have many, many different web services).  Is there a way I can post logs whenever an Intent is processed and then finished, and retrieve that log from his phone to analyze?

Comment: Use Log to post messages to Logcat at certain points in your service. Then trace them to see at which point the service is stuck. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I'd like to be able to let this run on his device, and he can hand it to me some point in the future and I can retrieve the logs.  I've never done this.  Is this possible?

Comment: You have to give him the code with the Log code added, he needs to debug it on Eclipse, copy Logcat, save it and send it to you. Otherwise, you can ask for his device and do it in a very short time when you meet. It won't take too long.

Comment: Does your webservices calls have a timeout set? are you creating any threads on your service? Are you calling your service with enough time to let the previous execution finish? It looks like something is blocking the service to finalize it's execution, and the rest of the started services are queued.

Comment: Cheek out [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212942/intentservice-not-getting-called-sometimes) and see if it match your symptoms. How do you manage the web service call in your application (sequentially or in parallel), it is probably due to previous http call hands which cause all subsequent call to wait in case if all http call are performed globally and sequentially.

Comment: My web service calls have a timeout of 10 seconds.  I am creating no threads.  I do have a data object which stores a list of the operation "types" currently sitting in the IntentService queue and adds a parameter to incoming Intents to "skip" that Intent if one for the same type already exists in the queue (I do this in onStartCommand).  I'll update the OP with this code.

Comment: You said onStartCommand() never hit, it's weird. it should be hit at least for very first startService() call. In onStartCommand(). you do nothing about the exception. I would uncomment the catch code and see if the problem is started from here.

Comment: Maybe adding some counter and log statements in onHandleIntent will help debug the issue (to make sure that its not blocked while processing any webservice call).

Comment: You could also ignore the call that you want to skip, by not calling the super onStartCommand method (and return 0)

Comment: at which state or event your are calling this 'appContext.startService(intent);' ?

Answer (score 4):

There is definitly something that keeps your service running on your friend's device. If so all subsequent call to this intent service are queued until the current one finishes. If it doesn't finish then you will get what you have : next services won't start.

You should double check that :

- you give proper timeouts to nework operations
- you give proper timeouts to nework connections operations
- there is no race condition between threads.
- you log any exception that can occur inside the service, you don't wanna loose that kind of information.

Afterwards, if you think everything is green : just log what the service does and use some bug reporting mechanism to get it automatically sent from your friends device. A simple solution could be to use bugsense or equivalent.

Next, put in place some kind of watchdog : a thread that will go on running until your service stops (you just tell your thread to stop when service is stopped). The thread will have to stop your service after some time limit has been passed.

This watchdog thread could be put inside the service itself, or outside, although this may be more complex to put in place.

Comment: Another thing that could be done do to check if that's the case is write your own service taking inspiration from the intentservice source code (which is quite simple) and have an "intentservice with probes" to perform more logging and watchdogging.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a race condition that would cause a problem?  Since an IntentService queues up messages, it really shouldn't matter what thread calls startService.  Or are you talking about a race condition within the IntentService processing the Intent (ie: the code I write inside the IntentService)?  None of my code there is asynchronous, so I don't think this should be an issue.  All of my web service calls have a timeout of 10 seconds.  Suppose, hypothetically, there were 100 messages queued up, these 10s would add up, but I've seen this happen both when he has wifi and cell.

Comment: By race condition I just meant that on of your service keeps running, never ending. As all intent services of the same class are queued by Android, all intent services must end after a certain timeout. And you are responsible for that, Android doesn't do any such thing automatically. Also get sure to have both a socket timeout and a connect timeout set for your network requests.

Answer (score 1):

This answer suggests a solution that worked for me in similar situations. It doesn't fix your current code but suggests another, perhaps simpler (and easier to debug) option:

1. Add a `BroadcastReceiver` to your calling `Activity` that listens for SUCCESS `Intents` from the `IntentService`.
2. In your calling `Activity`, include the logic for when to start the `IntentService` (and don't include it in the IntentService). The logic is:

   - Call `startService()` and set a flag in the calling `Activity` to CANNOT_CALL.
   - If the `Activity's` `BroadcastReceiver` has not received a SUCCESS broadcast from the `IntentService`, then `startService()` can not be called again.
   - When the `Activity` does receive a SUCCESS intent, set the flag to CAN_CALL, and `startService()` can be called when the timer hits again.
3. In your `IntentService`, write your `onStartCommand()` like so:

   ```
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       return START_STICKY;
   }
   ```
4. In you `IntentService`, when you've received, parsed and stores the web service response, call `sendBroadcast()` with an Intent with custom action SUCCESS.

This logic is just an outline and has to be fine-tuned for error messages from the web service that have to be broadcast from `IntentService` to the listening `Activity`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that setting a set of flags to your Intent may solve the problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(appContext, SyncService.class);
// This way    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

You can make your Service start as fresh using the above flag in a fresh task.

Answer (score 0):

One more comment. It's not an answer for your question. However, it may affect overall behavior of a service.

You do following:

```
 return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

Internally Service.onStartCommand() looks like following

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId); 
        return mStartCompatibility ? START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY : START_STICKY;
}
```

mStartCompatibility is false if your app target SDK API 7 or later (which is most likely a case).

So, as result your service will be started as START_STICKY.

Here is piece from documentation:

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them. See the linked documentation for more detail on the semantics.

Base on what you have described, I recommend to replace "return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);" to "return START_NOT_STICKY;"

Comment: I can't see the link with the question. Start sticky or start not sticky affect the behavior of a service when the system is under memory pressure and kills your app. It will restart any services declared sticky asap. This has, to my mind but I may be wrong, nothing to do with the fact that one service executes and never ends.

Comment: Wouldn't an IntentService always return START_NOT_STICKY?

Comment: 2Snicolas: I believe with a sticky service, system won't stop a service with it completes hanling current intent and with non sticky it will complete it. I just wanted to point this out to let know that service could be running for numerous reasons.

Comment: 2Andrew: Apparently, it's not. The piece of code which I put it is from Android Open Source project.